# Напишите программу для решения задачи, используя рекурсивную функцию:

Tags: c++

Найти -й член последовательности, заданной следующим образом:

z<sub>1</sub> = 3,
z<sub>n</sub> = n / z<sub>n-1</sub>

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

long z(int n) {
    if ( n == 1) return 3; 
    else return (n / z(n - 1)); }

int main() {
    int n; 
    cout << "Vvedite n\n"; 
    cin >> n; 
    cout << z(n) << "\n"; 
    return 0; }
```

выдает ошибку...

Comment: А что ж вы целочисленно делите?...

Comment: "выдает ошибку..."? Какую "ошибку", где и кто вам выдает? Почему эта информация отсутствует в вопросе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

первое почему long z() ?? далее int / long - зачем, не боитесь получить 0?

Вы не проверяете ввод.. введите строку и посмотрите что будет.

Вот Вам реализация Вашей задачи

```
#include <iostream> 


double z(int n) {
    if ( n == 1) {
        return 3;
    }

    return static_cast<double>(n) / z(n - 1);
}


int main() {
    int n{0};

    std::cout << "Input n : ";

    while (!(std::cin >> n) || n < 1) {
        std::cout << "Input error, try again " << std::endl;
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore();
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << z(n) << std::endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваша функция вычисляет следующее:

1. Первый член z1 = 3 , //ok
2. второй  z2 = long(2 / 3)  == 0 // плохо
   приехали...
3. третий член это z3 = long(3 / z2) = long(3 / 0)

А деление на ноль всегда является ошибкой...
Поэтому нужно исправить:

```
double z(int n) {
    if (n == 1) return 3;
    return (double )n / z(n - 1);
}
```

Comment: Лучше использовать static_cast<> C++ метка

Comment: Для встроенных типов нет необходимости. Можете показать как вы выполните static_cast при делении целых?

Comment: Страуструп пишет:
«Например, что это значит выражение — x = (T)y;. Мы не знаем. Это зависит от типа T, типов x и y. T может быть названием типа, typedef или может быть параметр template-а. Может быть, х и у являются скалярными переменными и Т представляет собой значение преобразования. Может быть, х объекта класса, производного от класса Y и Т — нисходящее преобразование. По этой причине программист может не знать, что он делает на самом деле.»
Вторая причина нежелательного использования приведения типов в C-style — трудоемкость процесса поиска мест приведения типов.

Comment: @Andrey, вот поэтому я и говорю, что для встроенных типов, которые используются и в C-style, нет необходимости для static_cast. Если можно проще, то не нужно загружать код лишными выражениями

Comment: каждому свое.. так читабельные лично для меня)